# Prove $ dy_1 \, dy_2=|J|\,dx_1 \, dx_2$, where $|J|$ is the determinant of the Jacobian.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose,$y_1=y_1(x_1,x_2)$ and $y_2=y_2(x_1,x_2)$,
such that,

$$dy_1=\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1}dx_1+\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2} \, dx_2$$

$$dy_2=\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1}dx_1+\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} \, dx_2$$

Then,I've taken the product of the above two,but unable to reach to the result.

Answer (score 1):

You need not the usual product, but the *exterior* product of the two (see Arnol'd's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*):
$$
dy_{1} \wedge dy_{2} = \left({\partial y_{1} \over \partial x_{1}} {\partial y_{2} \over \partial x_{2}}  - 
{\partial y_{1} \over \partial x_{2}} {\partial y_{2} \over \partial x_{1}} 
\right) dx_{1} \wedge dx_{2}.
$$
The expression in ()'s is your $J$.

Comment: The expression in ()'s is $J$, not $|J|.$

Comment: @zhw., thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y^1 = y^1(x^1,x^2)$ and $y^2 = y^2(x^1,x^2)$. Suppose also that;

$$\\$$

$$dy^1=\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1}dx^1+\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x^2}dx^2$$

$$dy^2=\frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}dx^1+\frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}dx^2 $$

Then we have;

$$dy^1dy^2 = dy^1 \wedge dy^2$ =\left( \frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1}dx^1+\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^2}dx^2\right) \wedge \left(\frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}dx^1+\frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}dx^2\right)$$

The above gives the following;

$$\\$$

$$ \left(\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}\right) dx^1\wedge dx^1 +  \left(\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}\right) dx^1\wedge dx^2 +  \left(\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}\right) dx^2\wedge dx^1 + \left(\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}\right) dx^2\wedge dx^2  $$

$$\\$$

Now recall that $dx^i \wedge dx^i = 0, dx^j \wedge dx^i = -dx^i \wedge dx^j$ and so you have;

$$\\$$

$$\left(\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}\right) dx^1\wedge dx^2 +  \left(\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}\right) dx^2\wedge dx^1 = \underbrace{ \left(\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}-\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1} \right)}_{\textbf{Jacobian}} \ dx^1\wedge dx^2  $$

Comment: This is the reason for when you are integrating and do a coordinate change, the Jacobian pops up after the parametrization in which you transition to the new (hopefully more simple) integral.

Comment: You have some indices wrong in this.